# Handle seven digits in decimal part of seconds in datetime string

Tags: python, datetime

When calling an API, I am getting seven digits in the decimal part of the seconds in datetime string. Below is the value that I got in response:

```
"startDateTime": "2020-09-16T10:02:38.5904496Z"
```

Clearly `5904496` are seven digits. If there would have been 6 digits then I would have used the below code to convert this into `datetime` object:

```
from datetime import datetime

datetime_object = datetime.strptime(startDateTime, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ')
```

But I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/_strptime.py", line 565, in _strptime_datetime
    tt, fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/_strptime.py", line 362, in _strptime
    (data_string, format))
ValueError: time data '2020-09-16T10:02:38.5904496Z' does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ'
```

**How do I handle 7 digits in decimal part of seconds?**

**P.S: I know I can use python `dateutil` library but I should know how to do this. I will really be thankful if you can shed some light on this.**

Comment: do you need the 7 digit accuracy?

Comment: @BendikKnapstad I am being honest. I knew that i could strip the seventh digit but i thought there may be a directive for ```10^(-7)``` just like we have %f for microseconds. So for my knowledge i asked this question. Thanks for the reference though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for completeness, `numpy`'s `datetime64` handles fractional seconds with nanosecond resolution:

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array(["2020-09-16T10:02:38.5904496Z"], dtype=np.datetime64)
print(arr[0])
>>> 2020-09-16T10:02:38.590449600
```

However, here it fails to parse `Z` to UTC. This works fine with `pandas`, as I show in the linked question's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63447899/10197418).

Comment: Since this is the accepted answer, I cannot delete it. Please follow the duplicate link for a more comprehensive answer.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't need the precision, just chop it off.

```
d = "2020-09-16T10:02:38.5904496Z"
datetime.datetime.strptime(d.split(".")[0], "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
```

Output: `datetime.datetime(2020, 9, 16, 10, 2, 38)`

If you want to keep it thou.

```
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime(d[:-2], "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f")
>>> datetime.datetime(2020, 9, 16, 10, 2, 38, 590449)
```

Comment: Precision is not an issue. I am being honest. I knew that i could strip the seventh digit but i thought there may be a directive for ```10^(-7)``` just like we have %f for microseconds. So for my knowledge i asked this question. Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: that ignores the fact that the input is UTC ('Z') - a thing to consider carefully when using Python since it does not default to UTC with its naive datetime type.